# Getting OAuth access token for Google Plus API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I m current developing an app for google plus. I want to fetch the access token from google plus API. I want to use OAuth 2.0 to fetch the access token. I have constructed to URL

"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=752264386186-
72f3ef2ok1j3k8g12h7hg8k5kjt9s9si.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https:
//www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code"

which when I pasted to by browser asks to sign in with my google account. So when I enter my credentials it asks for "allow access" or "no thanks" . when I click "allow access" it gives me the access token in my browser. I want the above steps to be done using my C# code.

How I can navigate to authorisation page from code and fetch the access token once the authentication is sucessful. Should I use httpwebrequest or webclient or rest sharp. Please provide me some sample code also.

Comment: There are OAuth 2.0 SDKs on the net, the problem you will find is, they are design with the intent of allowing the user to confirm the transaction.  You are not going to have much luck avoiding that part.

Comment: any links or sample code where I can refer to ?

Comment: Display it in a embedded WebBrowser control as its intended to be used, listen to the Navigating event, and look for the token

Comment: I tried to fetch the access token from navigation event argument e.uri.fragment but its null. So wanted to get the access token using a call back object. I want some help in using HttpWebRequest to get the access token from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the WebBrowser is okay for you, here is a simple example how I did the same thing with Foursquare API. This code has been written only to test how it goes, so I'm sure it's missing several important things like error handling etc.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string address =
            "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate" +
            "?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID +
            "&response_type=token" +
            "&redirect_uri=" + CALLBACK_URI;
        webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser1_Navigated);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(address, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        response = e.Uri.ToString();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Uri.ToString());
        if (response.LastIndexOf("access_token=") != -1)
        {
            string token = response.Substring(response.LastIndexOf("#access_token=") + "#access_token=".Length);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TOKEN: " + token);
        }
    }
```

Once you have allowed access, you end up getting the callback URI with the access_token. Note that webBrowser1_Navigated might get called several (each time you are navigating to another page in the embedded web browser).

Comment: sorry I have one question what is "response" type. when I declared response is of type HttpWebResponse its throwing an error.

Comment: It's a string got from e.Uri.ToString(). Though might be better to use e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.

Answer (score 0):

This code is EPIC, literally amazing.

Comment: Please put your comments in commenting area, not in answers..!! :)